React version 19 error : Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client
I am new to React JS and got a setup of react application through :
npx create-next-app@latest projectname
after taking lots of minute, setup completed with error :

i tried to google this error but didn't found any specific solution. Please help..!!
I tried to setup a react application and was expecting it to run smoothly as per documentation provided on https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project
In package.json :
React js version is 19.0.0
Next js version is 15.1.2
Below is the code of src\app\page.js :
<div className="demo"> Hello world </div>


This type of error often occurs when you use an unsymmetrical element that is not intended to be used in a certain way, such as wrapping a <p> tag inside another <p> tag. You can read more about it here:

How to solve React hydration error in Next.js
React hydration error - Next.js documentation

1 of the solution provided in second documentation is :
suppressHydrationWarning

i have added this option in top most parent tag and error gone.

Hello i have updated my question and provided the code to you..!!
